# Iterate with threshold stored in database

Tags: c#

I have a variable number of transactions in every month saved in the database. I have to calculate a payment according a structure like as 0-100 transaction, 1 € for every transaction, 101-200 2€ for each, 201 to 300 3€ for each, etc. The first 100 transactions I’ll pay 100 €, the next 100 transactions I’ll pay 200 € and in this way. Until here is easy for me, the problem become because the number of thresholds (in the earlier example was 3), can be variable, sometimes is 3, other times could be 2, 4, 5 or whatever. These thresholds are stored in a table in the database. Please, can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Please, can someone help me ...* help you with what? there is no question and no effort shown fro your end.

Comment: Q: What is your database?  An RDBMS?  MS SqlServer? Q: How are the transatcions ordered?  For example, is there a date/time field in the transaction record?  Q: Exactly how are the "thresholds" defined?  Can you show us a "select"?  Q: *CAN YOU SHOW US SOME CODE*???

Comment: What does "number of thresholds" mean? You say in your example there were 3, do you refer to 0-100, 101-200 and 201-300? Because you said "etc.,", so I understand there's also 301-400, 401-500... Or do you mean that with 3 thresholds, 3€ is for 201-infinite? BTW, saying "please help" is highly discouraged here. Also, what do you exactly need? Given a specific # of transaction, do you want to calculate its corresponding payment? Or the accumulated payments? That is, for 102, do you want "2" or "104"?

Comment: @Jose, still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each threshold in the database, you will sore a LOWER and UPPER bound and Price (0,100,1),(101,200,2),(201,300,3).

Load the thresholds into a List with each member containing the lower, upper, and price

```
List<int[]> thresholds = new List<int[]>
thresholds.Add(new int[]{0,100,1});
thresholds.Add(new int[]{101,200,2);//etc.

private void calculateTotal(int numberSold){
    int total =0;
    foreach(int[] bound in thresholds){
        if(numberSold>=bound[0]&&numberSold<=bound[1]{
            total+= bound[2]*numberSold;
         }
     }
     return total;
 }
```

That's about the best I can do for you based on your limited question. Play with this and if you have a problem, ask a specific question based on the code you create and the specific problem you are having.